# Two files in /etc/logrotate.d/ trying to manage the same log file

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

If there are two separate config files in /etc/logrotate.d/ that are trying to manage the same log file in different ways, what happens? Is one preferred over the other? Would I have to delete one of the config files?

For example:
Two configurations - /etc/logrotate.d/A and /etc/logrotate.d/B

Contents of A:

```
/var/log/example.log {
    rotate 4
    weekly
}
```

Contents of B:

```
/var/log/example.log {
    rotate 3
    weekly
    compress
}
```

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual scenario, the files in `/etc/logrotate.d` are all read in by an `include` directive in the main `/etc/logrotate.conf` file.  If you have multiple directives matching the same file in such a setup, you will get an error:

> ```
> error: /etc/logrotate.conf:line_number duplicate log entry for logfile_path
> error: found error in logfile_path, skipping
> ```